# What is the probability of equal number of Heads when coin is tossed large number of times (say 10000)

Tags: probability

As per basic probability theorem getting equal number of heads and tails when coin is tossed $10000$ times is
= $\frac{\binom{n}{r}}{2^n} = \frac{\binom{10000}{5000}}{2^{10000}}$

This value is not equal to or close to $0.5$

But if one does the same experiment simulation, then probability will be close to $0.5$ (with $10000$ tosses)

Can you explain why is there a difference in probability ?

Comment: Have you done the simulation?

Comment: No, I followed this link for simulation data: [link](http://ucanalytics.com/blogs/right-sample-size-analysis/)

Comment: I think you misunderstood the results, nowhere  do they give the probability of seeing _exactly_ the same amount of heads and tails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The probability being close to $1/2,$ has to do with relative error; namely since
$$
\frac{\binom{n}{n/2}}{2^n}\approx \frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi n}}
$$
by Stirling approximation, the probability of being within $O(\sqrt{n})$ terms, i.e. within $O(\frac{\sqrt{n}}{2^n})$ of the of the exact $1/2$ probability value goes to $1$ as $n$ increases.